# Build node-sqlite3 addon for armv7l

Tags: docker, sqlite, node.js-addon, node-sqlite3

**How to build the node.js addon "[node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)" for a `armv7l` (32 bit) target using docker?**

The following information may be usefull for others, that just want to use [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) on `arm`:

- Debian provides a package [node-sqlite3](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/node-sqlite3) also for `armhf`, that also works on `armv7l`.
- There is a fork [louislam/node-sqlite3](https://github.com/louislam/node-sqlite3) that provides [a docker file](https://github.com/louislam/node-sqlite3/blob/master/build-arm.dockerfile) to build a basic `arm` binding. But it looks like it does not support the 32-bit architecture of `armv7l`.

Comment: Is this a question of how to build any native addon for `armv7l` or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @mmomtchev As far as I can see node-sqlite3 does not provide any armv7l bindings, yet. So the question is less how to build native addons for arm but how to build this library in particular.

Comment: I think that if you checkout that repo and then replace `arm` with `armv7l` in the Dockerfile, you have very good chances of getting quite far - especially if sqlite3 has already good `armv7l` support